# Apply different animations to multiple backgrounds images in a single class

Tags: html, css, animation, slider, slideshow

I have a single class named slider .I need to have different types of animation for different images.Please help me to implement that .Now all my images are having same mode of animation.I just want to keep a single  class slider.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
       body{
           margin:0p;
           padding:0p;
          background: green;
          perspective: 800px;
          height: 100vh;
   width: 100wh;
       
       }
        .slider{
        /*    background-image: url(https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/logos/firefox/logo-quantum.9c5e96634f92.png);
  background-size: 800px 800px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: pink;
         */
        width:100vw;
         height:100vh;
            background: url(b1.jpg);

  background-size: 100wh 100vh;   
 /* animation: slide 2s infinite;*/
  animation: slide 
   2s infinite;                                                   
  margin: 100px auto;
         
        }
    @keyframes slide{
        from{
           /* transform:rotateY(0deg);*/
          /* transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0deg);*/
           transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  background-color: pink;
        }
        to{
           /* transform:rotateY(180deg); 
            transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 360deg);*/
            transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
  background-color: pink;
        }  
      
            25%{
                background-image: url(b2.jpg);
               
 
                background-size: 100wh 100vh;   
 
            }
            50%{
                background-image: url(b3.jpg);
                

                background-size: 100wh 100vh;   
            }
            75%{
                background-image: url(b4.jpg);
                

                background-size: 100wh 100vh;     
            }
            100%{
                background-image: url(b5.jpg);
                

                background-size: 100wh 100vh;    
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hellomidhun2020/x0nuhbg9/4/)

Also one more doubt in each image there seems to be a repetition of image as if the same image gets reduced and a part of the image is getting added there .I just want to have a single image with 100% view not repetition.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me, pls elaborate it a little and as for the image repetition you can add ```no repeat``` to ```.slider``` like ```.slider{background: url(b1.jpg) no repeat;}```

Comment: @Uzair  I am trying to animate different images as the keyframe goes from 0% to 25% and from 25% to 50% and so on ...but how can i give different type of animation .. as if second image gets rotated from 0 degree to 140 degree and third image zooms in and fades out like that... here every image have same model of animation

Comment: if you want to apply different animations then i think you will have to define another animation i.e keyfames and then use it on different image classes seperately

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Uzair ..But no repeat didn't work  https://jsfiddle.net/hellomidhun2020/wq5kptxu/4/

Comment: its ```no-repeat``` actually but doing so will show only one image and it wont get rid of the portion at the end, also the portion at the end isn't due to CSS, i's simply because of the viewport, try zooming in and out and you will see that the image at the end will show up fully and partly respectively

Comment: @Uzair thanks man for the suggestion .But that is not showing justice to animation as the image shrinks to a reduced size .. so i cant go that way ..Can you fork the fiddle and give me a working example.. I will be grateful to you. Appreciate your awesome character to help me

Comment: Well the repitition of images can be solved by replacing the values of `background-size: 100vw 100vh to cover` (also you had a typo in the same property there is nothing like "wh" in css)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a slider and looking at the keyframes definition it seems as though you want to rotate a set of images in order using one animation, not different animations for each image. Tfhis is doable as long as you don't want totally different animations for each 'slide'.

A couple of points:
Your 'doubt' is justified. The image is being repeated as that is the default for background in CSS, set it to 'no-repeat' so you don't get the little extra bits.

The images may (or may not, depends on your use case, but in general) have differing aspect ratios and they may be different or not from the aspect ratio of the viewport (which the containing element uses to set its dimensions). Use either `background-size: contain` to ensure you see the whole image for every one, or `cover` if you want to have the entire viewport covered, though in that case either the top and bottom or the side may get cropped to fit

You probably want the `background-position` to be centered both horizontally and vertically rather than left and top which would be the default in this case.

Here's an altered snippet. Note that the sizes transform over a short time which you may or may not want. You can alter the keyframes to stop that (let me know if you need help with that). Also the very last image has no time to show itself so you probably want to look at the % settings to make sure it gets a look in.

```css
body {
  margin: 0p;
  padding: 0p;
  background: green;
  perspective: 800px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
}

.slider {
  /*    background-image: url(https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/logos/firefox/logo-quantum.9c5e96634f92.png);
  background-size: 800px 800px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: pink;
         */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1023/300/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  /* ADDED */
  background-position: center center;
  /* ADDED */
  background-size: cover;
  /* ADDED - TRY BOTH TO DECIDE WHICH YOU WANT IF YOU HAVE IMAGES OF DIFFERENT ASPECT RATIOS */
  background-size: contain;
  /* ADDED */
  background-size: 100wh 100vh;
  /* animation: slide 2s infinite;*/
  animation: slide 2s infinite;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    /* transform:rotateY(0deg);*/
    /* transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0deg);*/
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
    background-color: pink;
  }
  to {
    /* transform:rotateY(180deg); 
            transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 360deg);*/
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
    background-color: pink;
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
    background-size: 100wh 100vh;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/768/1024);
    background-size: 100wh 100vh;
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/300);
    background-size: 100wh 100vh;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1020/300/300);
    background-size: 100wh 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider"></div>
```

**UPDATE**
In the above snippet each image gets the same animation. The requirement is for each to have its own (rotation, zoom et al). This can be achieved while still maintaining the single slider class requirement by having each part of the keyframes define the animation for that particular slide.

In this snippet there are 4 slides, each takes one quarter of the overall alloted time for one iteration of the animation. In each part the particular animation required is defined. This snippet assumes that you want to do the animation bit for half the time an image has the show it without moving for the remaining half. These timings can be altered by altering the %s in the keyframes.

The first image rotates, the second image zooms, the third image comes in from 0 opacity and the fourth image just shows without moving.

Obviously more images can be added and different types of movement, scaling, opacity defined by altering %s and inserting more background images.

Note: opacity will refer to the whole element, so the backgroud pink color also faded which looked odd so I removed it. If it is important to have a background you will have to think about an extra element and animating that, or decide not to use opacity as one of the things that change, or have green to pink change anyway.

```css
body {
  margin: 0p;
  padding: 0p;
  background: green;
  perspective: 800px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
}

.slider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  /* ADDED */
  background-position: center center;
  /* ADDED */
  background-size: cover;
  /* ADDED - TRY BOTH TO DECIDE WHICH YOU WANT IF YOU HAVE IMAGES OF DIFFERENT ASPECT RATIOS */
  background-size: contain;
  /* ADDED */
  animation: slide 16s infinite;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1023/300/300);
  }
  12.5%,
  24.99% {
    /* to make the slide not move between those times */
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1023/300/300);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
  }
  37.5%,
  49.99% {
    /* so it scales up for the first half of its time, then stays there showing */
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg) scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/768/1024);
  }
  74.99% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/768/1024);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/300);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/300);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider"></div>
```

The overall aimation has time of 16s to give each image 2 seconds to move and 2 seconds staying still.

You will find that you need to play around with opacity to stop very sudden changes if this is a problem.

The snippet repeats both the transform and the opacity setting each time which is not always necessary, but I find it serves as a reminder that transform needs all the settings in it, it's not 'cumulative'.

Comment: @A Hawoth Thanks for the fabulous explanation .. but what i am trying to accomplish is .. in each transition should be different as if the first frame rotates from 0 degree to 360 degree .. the second transition should be just zoom in and fade out... like that... is it possible  ..here all animations are rotating from 0 degree to 360 degree ..can you help me

Comment: as if for 25 % of transition i need to apply one form of animation and for the next 25% i need another type of animation and so on... Is it possible @AHaworth

Comment: Ah, that is indeed different. You may be able to do it in just the one animation with one class as you specify but is the time each slide shows the same or does that differ too?

Comment: Our comments crossed at the same time! I see that you want the same timing for each animation as you've given 25% as an example. Yes you can do that. I'll put up a second snippet, may take a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot A Hawoth .. for you awesome support ...I am trying to implement a slider as if in this site.,... https://www.karplab.net/  but here we need to click the arrow in slider to get it changed i need it done in after a certain period of milliseconds.. .

Comment: I've just had a look at the karplab site. On an iPad they automatically move to another slide. While you could emulate most of what they do in a single animated element I am not sure you could do their animated split images coming together as you can't animate background images as such, only the element holding that background image. Might be possible if we bring in pseudo before/after elements as well though. Let me know if that is a requirement.

Comment: @A Haworth ..that split image is shall implement with a gif animation.. rest can we do